# How do I search for a string of numbers with Excel vlookup, only return the ones in the desired range, then sort the results?

Tags: excel, vlookup

This is for a budget. I have the day of the month in one column (1, 2, 3, etc.) and the payment amount of the bill in the right hand adjacent column. I have a variable set of budget dates listed in two separate cells. I want to have a formula that takes all the days between the budget dates (would be nice if it also included the beginning and ending budget dates) searches the list of bills and returns the payments of those between the dates. For example, budget beginning date is 1, budget ending date is 13. There's a list of bills with random dates (1, 3, 4, 14, 18, 23, etc.). The formula would search the list of bills for any bill with the date 1-13 and return the payment for any matches (ex. it would return the payment for 1, 3, and 4 in the example but skip the rest). All matches would be listed in date order in separate cells. Then, if the beginning and ending dates were changed the formula would adjust without any additional input. See attached image.[image]

Comment: Are you using Excel365?  If so, use `FILTER`

Comment: I'm using version 16.56. Looks like I have the FILTER option in this version. Just need to figure it out

Comment: Something like `=Filter(PaymentColumn, (DateColumn>=Start)*(DateColumn<=End))`

Comment: Been playing around with FILTER as well as other functions. Finally got FILTER to work as long as the beginning and ending dates where in sequential order. However, it fails when a budget overlaps the end of the month and the beginning date is a higher number than the ending date (ex. beginning date 24, end date 6). The formula doesn't know to start over at 30/31 for the end of the months. Thoughts on this?

Comment: Maybe `=IF(Start>End, Filter(PaymentColumn, (DateColumn>=Start)*(DateColumn<=End)), Filter(PaymentColumn, (DateColumn<Start)*(DateColumn>End))`

Comment: Can't get that to work. Still can't find a formula that will work if the start date is higher in value than the end date. My current formula is =FILTER(Budget!N13:P23,(Budget!N13:N23>=B1)*(Budget!N13:N23<=B2),"No results")

Comment: I think I could do it a different way if I could find a formula that would automatically move up my debit dates every month. This would allow to use DATEVALUE and that would always keep the end date larger than the start date. But I need a formula to for example change 11/26/2021 to 12/26/2021 on the 11/26 then change it to 01/26/2021 on 12/26. Can seem to find a date function that will automatically do that without some manual input.

Comment: Figured it out. Kinda messy but works. Used the formula IF(TODAY()>DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),N14),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,N14), TODAY()) where N14 is the day of the month the bill is due (ex. 29). Then by changing by start and end dates to actual date format it works no matter what the dates are.